# PostgreSQL function to check for an enum value in an array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, enums, postgresql-9.2

Types:

```
CREATE TYPE equipment AS ENUM ('projector','PAsystem','safe','PC','phone');
CREATE TYPE building_code AS ENUM ('IT','EMS','HSB','ENG');
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE venue (
   id INTEGER DEFAULT NEXTVAL('venue_id_seq')
 , building_code building_code
 , floorNo int
 , roomNo int
 , width int
 , length int
 );

CREATE TABLE lecture_room (
   id INTEGER DEFAULT NEXTVAL('lecture_id_seq')
 , seatCount int
 , equipment equipment[]
) INHERITS(venue);
```

Function:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION hasProjector(_id int ) RETURNS boolean AS 
$$
code to check if there exists a projector in the equipment array of lecture_room
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I am not 100% sure on the SQL code to put in the function and how to get a boolean as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ANY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME) to check whether the array contains a certain element:

```
SELECT TRUE
FROM   lecture_room
WHERE  id = _id
AND    'projector' = ANY (equipment)
```

Returns TRUE or NULL. If you need TRUE / FALSE use [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS):

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   lecture_room
   WHERE  id = _id
   AND    'projector' = ANY (equipment)
   )
```

BTW, in this case, you don't need an explicit cast (`'projector'::equipment`), but it wouldn't hurt either.